# RxSwift: Two way binding

Tags: ios, swift, data-binding, rx-swift

I used [official two-way-binding solution](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Operators.swift)

```
func <-> <T>(property: ControlProperty<T>, variable: Variable<T>) -> Disposable{
let bindToUIDisposable = variable.asObservable()
    .bindTo(property)

let bindToVariable = property
    .subscribe(onNext: { n in
        variable.value = n
    }, onCompleted:  {
        bindToUIDisposable.dispose()
    })

return Disposables.create(bindToUIDisposable, bindToVariable)
}
```

Usage: `(textField.rx.text <-> object.property).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)`

Property definition: `var property = Variable<String?>(nil)`

1. In onNext method all ok and `variable` changed its value, but my `object.property` doesn't changed.
2. Is there any way to set variable current value into ControlProperty inside of <-> method, bcs I need set initial value, before subscribe starts?

Answer (score 4):

***Working in Swift 4***

---

**Example of two way binding between String & Textfield with MVVM architecture:**

- In ViewController:

---

```
 @IBOutlet weak var emailTextfield: UITextField!
 var viewModel : CCRegisterViewModel?
```

- In ViewModel:

---

```
var email = Variable<String>("")
```

- Use this code in ViewController

---

```
viewModel?.email.asObservable()
.bind(to: emailTextfield.rx.text)
.disposed(by: disposeBag)

emailTextfield.rx.text.orEmpty.bind(to:viewModel!.email)
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1):

My fault. I replaced object with another instance after binding

This code works well and control property receive initial value from variable