# RxSwift initial value when binding a Variable

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have the following code:

```
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class ViewModel {

    var text = Variable<String>("")

    init() {
        text.value = "hello"
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!

    var viewModel = ViewModel()

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textView.rx.text
            .orEmpty
            .debug()
            .bind(to: viewModel.text)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

The binding works fine (when I change the `UITextView` it properly updates the `viewModel`. However, since the binding is unidirectional (or so I understand), the `textView` doesn't start with the value I set in the `ViewModel`'s `init` method.

I can do `textView.text = viewModel.text.value` just before the binding, but since I'm using RxSwift, I want to understand what's the usual practice here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, this is a unidirectional binding and you'd have to set the initial value of your text view manually.
If you want bidirectional binding, take a look at the following code:

[RxSwift: Two way binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323049/rxswift-two-way-binding)

Be sure to import the Operators.swift file in your project (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Operators.swift)

Note that the Variable type must be `Variable<String?>`, as text is an optional String in UIKit.